# angularjs how can pass multipul parameter to api

Tags: angularjs

How can I pass mutipul parameters from angularjs -to WebAPi My Api as its Required two parameters

```
public IHttpActionResult GetData(int pagesize,int Totalpages){---}
```

**angularctrls.js**

```
function GetData() {
        var PageDetails={
            'currentpage': $scope.currentPage,
            'pagesize':$scope.pagesize
        }    
        HomeFactory.GetDat(PageDetails).then(function () {
        })
    }
```

**Factory.js**

```
 EmployeeServiceFactory.GetDat = function (PageDetails) {
        return $http({
            url:WebAPi+'Home/GetData/',
            method: 'GET',
            data: PageDetails,
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
        })
}
```

Getting Error as

```
Failed to load http://localhost:3084/Home/GetData/%7B%22currentpage%22:1,%22pagesize%22:5%7D: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource
```

Comment: when i convert data in Json obj its throughing an error as A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:).

Comment: Maybe your back doesn't accept multiple keys as data

Comment: why not its suppport

Comment: correct this from `url:WebAPi+'Home/GetData/'+PageDetails` to `url:WebAPi+'Home/GetData/'` and methode ? should be method @MdGhousemohi and is your response status 404 ?

Comment: @supercool when i change url as your suggest even im getting same Error   And My response is404

Comment: @MdGhousemohi else keep it as is `url:WebAPi+'Home/GetData/'+PageDetails and remove `data: PageDetails,` as GET requests doesn't have body only POST does .

Comment: else keep it as is `url:WebAPi+'Home/GetData/'+PageDetails and remove `data: PageDetails,` as GET requests doesn't have body only post does .

Comment: @Supercoll GET http://localhost:3084/Home/GetData/%7B%22currentpage%22:1,%22pagesize%22:5%7D 400 (Bad Request)    im getting this Error

Comment: @MdGhousemohi `Home/GetData` did u configure ur route engine . by default API calls will be kindoff `api/{youControllerName}` . ur API are on `c#`  or any

Comment: Yes Its C#  and i did nt configure any rote

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160806/discussion-between-super-cool-and-md-ghousemohi).

Comment: have you added access-control-allow-origin header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `params` instead of `data` like below:

```
  EmployeeServiceFactory.GetDat = function (PageDetails) {
            return $http({
                url:WebAPi+'Home/GetData/',
                method: 'GET',
                params: PageDetails,
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
            })
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can put data as an object.

```
EmployeeServiceFactory.GetDat = function (PageDetails) { 
  return $http({ 
    url:WebAPi+'Home/GetData/'+PageDetails, 
    method: 'GET', 
    data: {page_details: 
      PageDetails, foo: 'bar'}, headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' 
    } 
  }) 
}
```